# Allow auto-fill to break words

Tags: auto-fill-mode

By default, `auto-fill` will only break a line at a whitespace character. Usually this is what you want. However, I'm writing a major mode for editing data files (DNA sequences) that contain long lines of text with no spaces, and I want them to auto-fill at exactly 80 columns. How can I achieve this?

i.e., I want to use auto-fill (or similar) to fill this:

```
ACCATCGAAACTTTGAACGCAAGTTGCGCCTCAAGCCATTAGGTTGAGGGCACGTTTGCTTGGGTGTCATTCGTTATGTC
```

to this (using 20-character lines instead of 80 for a shorter example):

```
ACCATCGAAACTTTGAACGC
AAGTTGCGCCTCAAGCCATT
AGGTTGAGGGCACGTTTGCT
TGGGTGTCATTCGTTATGTC
```

Comment: Is the purpose of this for easy reading only? If so, you can size the buffer to any convenient width and do `M-x toggle-truncate-lines`. Having `(setq-default truncate-partial-width-windows nil)` in your config would help if you want the line wrapping to work in frames with split windows.

Comment: @KaushalModi no, I want to be able to re-wrap the sequences after changing them. For instance, I may need to delete the first few letters from a row, and then re-fill what's left into 80-column lines.

Comment: Toggling truncation will give you the same effect. That's why I asked if it is important for you to see the wrapping just visually or is it also important to save the newlines to the file as well.

Comment: @KaushalModi oh, I've been sloppy with my language. When I said 're-wrap' (i.e., temporary visual change) I meant 're-fill' (i.e., add and remove newlines as necessary for a permanent change).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could modify the [category](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Categories.html#Categories) of characters `G`, `C`, `A`, and `T` to make them line-breakable:

```el
(defun break-at-gcat ()
  "Make characters G, C, A, and T line-breakable to simplify
wrapping DNA sequence strings."
  (dolist (char '(?G ?C ?A ?T))
    (modify-category-entry char ?|)))
```

Now if I evaluate `(break-at-gcat)`, set `fill-column` to 20,

```el
(setq-local fill-column 20)
```

put the cursor on this line,

```el
ACCATCGAAACTTTGAACGCAAGTTGCGCCTCAAGCCATTAGGTTGAGGGCACGTTTGCTTGGGTGTCATTCGTTATGTC
```

and press `M-q` (`fill-paragraph`), I get this:

```el
ACCATCGAAACTTTGAACGC
AAGTTGCGCCTCAAGCCATT
AGGTTGAGGGCACGTTTGCT
TGGGTGTCATTCGTTATGTC
```

To allow re-wrapping without inserting spaces we can use

```el
(setq-local sentence-end "[GCAT]")
```

This tricks `canonically-space-region` in `fill.el` into thinking that characters `G`, `C`, `A`, and `T` match the end a sentence (*including* the break we want) so it removes any extra spaces.

Note that *both* modifying character categories and the `sentence-end` regexp **will** mess with wrapping English text in the same buffer!

Comment: Neat, but once the string is splitted in lines, changing `fill-column` and using `M-q` again inserts white space inside the text.  Can this be avoided?

Comment: Thanks Constantine. I hadn't come across character categories before. I found the same problem mentioned by @JeanPierre. If there isn't a way to correct that, it shouldn't be hard to make a custom function to clean up the extra spaces.

Comment: @Tyler: Please see the updated answer.

Comment: @JeanPierre: Yes, I saw this too. I think setting `sentence-end` takes care of it, though -- please see the updated answer.

Comment: Great, thanks! These files won't have any English text, so this won't cause any problems.